# Getting error while installing Ionic on Windows 7

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, phonegap-cli

I am new in mobile application development. White Installing Ionic in My Windows 7, I am getting below errors.

[image]

My Installed Node version : 6.9.1

My Installed PhoneGap Version : 6.3.4

My Installed Cordova Version : 6.3.1

I have also tried using Node older version but no success.

Please help me to install it proper.

Thanks in advance. 
Sandip Mistry

Comment: update your java version to 8 then try again.

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps: create the `npm` folder in `AppData` folder and, optionally, reinstall Node.js.